# Setting ManipulationMode="Control" causes lag

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I want to detect CompositeTransform's `TranslateY` of ListBox. For this it's necessary to set the ListBox `ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode="Control"`.

However, it causes lag when the listbox is dragged. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you read following article on [ScrollViewer performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/02/listbox-scrollviewer-performance-improvement-for-mango-and-how-it-impacts-your-existing-application.aspx).

The MSDN remarks for [ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.manipulationmode%28VS.95%29.aspx) says

> In Windows Phone OS 7.1, the ManipulationMode property enables you to
>   specify how most of the property updates and events associated with
>   scrolling a ScrollViewer are handled. You can specify that the system
>   will handle the manipulations or that you will handle the
>   manipulations at the control level. **In most cases, to ensure smooth
>   scrolling, you should let the system handle the manipulations, which
>   is the default behavior**.

As you can see, it's unlikely you'll be able to get smooth scrolling and virtualization, when setting the `ManipulationMode`. What precisely do you need the `TranslateY` value for?

Comment: I need to detect ListBox Top with TranslateY .

Comment: I asked you *why* you needed to detect the value.

Comment: I need to detect ListBox is at Top or Bottom with TranslateY  to add items . I know i can detect ListBox with VerticalOffset but ....

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx

Comment: @ClausJørgensen so it's hard to achive smoothness with Pull to refresh, because it needs to detect TranslateY